# HttpClientHandler:Dispose (bool)' is inaccessible from method `System.Net.ServicePointManager:CloseConnectionGroup (string)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

> "HttpClientHandler:Dispose (bool)' is inaccessible from method
>   `System.Net.ServicePointManager:CloseConnectionGroup (string)"

this error occures when sending request, how to solve it?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlTemplate);
  client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
  var connectionString = string.Format(UrlTemplate, method.ToString().ToLower(), CreateParametrsString(parametrs));
  var response = await client.GetAsync(connectionString);
  if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader((await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")))
      {
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var json = content;
        var ass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        if (ass != null)
          Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("=>GETTED [{0}] table.", typename));
        else
          LoggingService.Report(null, new Dictionary<string, string> {
             { "request",typename },
             { "content",content },
             });
          return ass;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely running into a bug within the mono framework. I believe it's

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41133

There are two pull requests that address this issue:

https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/4277 (Master fix)

https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/4278 (Cycle9 fix inside mono 4.8)

The current Mono version that includes this fix is:

https://github.com/mono/mono/releases/tag/mono-4.8.0.478

Thus you will need a build that includes this or a later version.

https://github.com/mono/mono/commits/084f91256b05249f5f35973019561e6fefbdc053/mono/utils/mono-sha1.c

Thus this should be included in the current `Beta` channel build:

https://releases.xamarin.com/beta-release-cycle-9-rc-refresh-builds3/